# LineChart avoid plotting of 0 values

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts library. I am trying to remove 0 values from the chart but not able to find a particular solution any help would be appreciated.
yAxis has the value of type `Double`
The chart currently displays:

[image]

The updated line chart as I want

[image]

```
 var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []
        
 for i in 0..<forX.count {
            
   let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: forY[i])
   print(dataEntry)
   dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
           
}
        
let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
      
let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
chart.data = lineChartData
```

Comment: Please add your code, images are not very useful.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I tried some solutions but not able to get the result code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't add it to your dataEntries

```
for i in 0..<forX.count {
   if forY[i] != 0 {
       let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: forY[i])
       print(dataEntry)
       dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
   }
}
```

edit: you can check this https://github.com/aiwiguna/ExampleCharts

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't want to remove 0.0 from yAxis but not to display line on chart which has 0.0 value for xAxis label

Comment: 0.0 in xAxis or yAxis?

Comment: I updated my answer, I still not sure which axis value you want to check, but you just need to change the condition

Comment: I did the same thing before your answer  but it gives me error `Fatal error: Double value cannot be converted to Int because it is either infinite or NaN` and image updated

Comment: In library file at `let intervalMagnitude = pow(10.0, Double(Int(log10(interval)))).roundedToNextSignficant()`

Comment: is there any entry in your dataEntries after the filter?

Comment: can you share more of your code so I can try recreate your project?

Comment: can you share you chart setup? i cannot reproduce your error

Comment: I tried with your code but got result like no data for the chart which I don't want

Comment: I try to recreate what you want, and it no problem https://imgur.com/a/u9gT9ub I think it some other chart setup you did that trigger the error

Comment: my code only something like this https://pastebin.com/MbdukFBY

Comment: good luck to solve the problem, I already using this library and the original android version so many time lol

Comment: aiwiguna, can you please look at the updated question, I don't think so your provided solutions work for this case

Comment: Kishan, i need to know how your x and y value data, the same solution is working for me, just need some XAxis custom formatter

Comment: YAxis has a type of `Double` data and I already using custom formatter for XAxis

Comment: check this https://github.com/aiwiguna/ExampleCharts

Comment: @aiwiguna, are you facing issue like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62830642/chart-viewport-height-increase-when-chart-has-no-data-plot-on-chart in the chart