# Chart viewport height increase when chart has no data plot on chart

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts library. When the chart has no data then chart height increased it should be the same as when the chart has data. Chart xAxis labels overlapped with char title. Any help would be appreciated. Code for chart setup

```
var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

        axisFormatDelegate = self
        chartView.legend.form = .none
        
        let rightAxis = chartView.rightAxis
        rightAxis.enabled = false
        
        let yAxis = chartView.leftAxis
       
        let xAxisValue = chartView.xAxis
        xAxisValue.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate
        
        xAxisValue.axisMinimum = -1
        xAxisValue.axisMaximum = Double(forX.count)
        xAxisValue.granularity = 1
        
        for i in 0..<forX.count {
            
            if forY[i] != 0 {
                
                let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: forY[i])
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
            }
            
        }
        

        let lineChartDataSet = LineChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
        let lineChartData = LineChartData(dataSet: lineChartDataSet)
        print("Line chart data: \(lineChartData.dataSets)")
        chartView.data = lineChartData
```

The chart with data:

[image]

The chart with no data:

[image]

Comment: share your chart setup code, i think there is problem in the chart setup

Comment: @aiwiguna code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it because you set legend.form to .none, it not showing legend but still had space for it

I usually use this to hide legend and to give extra margin in bottom of xAxis label use

```
chartView.legend.enabled = false
chartView.extraBottomOffset = 10
```